# You are Here ${}{}$

Tags: riddle

You are Here
You are a traveller
You have travelled to many places
Europe
Japan
China
Russia
Mexico
But what is your name?

Comment: Not sure if riddle or Dad joke :P

Comment: @Doge So 'your name' is Carl?

Comment: those countries have all been thought to be smack in the middle of a theoretical WW III at one point, i'm having trouble seeing how that could be coincidence, red herring? (no Europe is not a country, i'm saying the others are)

Comment: @Space They were the first countries to pop into my head that weren't North American

Comment: Europe is not a country, and Mexico is part of North America...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My name is

> Here, because you said so in the title and again in the first line.

Comment: ...   that's seriously it? ...    well that's dissapointing

Answer (score 6):

Your name is:

> [image]

refresh the page and you'll see the answer

> [image]

Comment: How does this happen?

Comment: I don't get that when I refresh the page...

Comment: You can also see that by hitting the edit button beneath the question. Not convinced this is the answer though...

Comment: No, I just didn't know what to add to lengthen the title. It was too short. So I abused the math stuff and made an invisible part.

Answer (score 1):

> Here (from the very first line and the title, no less)